# Missing argument error for .get method of tkinter text entry widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am attempting to run the following code for a text editor.

```
def newfile():
current = None
def create_file(entry):
    nonlocal current
    current = open(entry.get(),'w')
    e.master.destroy()
chdir(askdirectory())
name=Tk()
name.title("Name the File?")
prompt=Label(name, text="Enter name for new file:")
prompt.grid(row=0)
e=Entry(name)
e.grid(row=1)
e.insert(0, "Untitled")
create=Button(name, text="Create", command = lambda: create_file(e))
create.grid(row=2, column=3)
name.mainloop()
return current
```

But I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1402, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 15, in <lambda>
    create=Button(name, text="Create", command = lambda: create_file(e))
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 5, in create_file
    current = open(entry.get(),'w')
TypeError: an integer is required
```

It wants an integer argument.
Does anyone know what that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance of the Entry widget does not require any arguments for the `get` method. You are calling it correctly. Neither does the standard `open` command require an integer. My guess is, one of `entry` or `open` is not what you think it is. Maybe you have a method or another object with one of those names?

I suggest putting the call to `get` and the open on separate lines, to make sure you know which part of that statement is throwing the error:

```
text = entry.get()
current = open(text, 'w')
```

Comment: Thanks, this should help track it down.

Comment: As it turns out, it wants the open function to have an integer, not the entry.get().