# Missing argument error for open function

Tags: python-3.x, arguments

I am trying to run this code for a text editor:

```python3
def newfile():
  current = None
  def create_file(entry):
    nonlocal current
    new_name=entry.get()
    current = open(new_name,'w')
    e.master.destroy()
  chdir(askdirectory())
  name=Tk()
  name.title("Name the File?")
  prompt=Label(name, text="Enter name for new file:")
  prompt.grid(row=0)
  e=Entry(name)
  e.grid(row=1)
  e.insert(0, "Untitled")
  create=Button(name, text="Create", command = lambda: create_file(e))
  create.grid(row=2, column=3)
  name.mainloop()
  return current
```

But I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1402, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 16, in <lambda>
    create=Button(name, text="Create", command = lambda: create_file(e))
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 6, in create_file
    current = open(new_name,'w')
TypeError: an integer is required
```

It wants the `open` function to have an integer argument in there somewhere, but as far as I know, `open` doesn't take any integers as required arguments. Whatever it is, it's enough to raise an error and keep this from running. Does anyone know what it is looking for?

Note that this is not the same question as [Missing argument error for .get method of tkinter text entry widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461940/missing-argument-error-for-get-method-of-tkinter-text-entry-widget).  I posted that question when I thought that it was the `.get()` method that was causing python to throw the error, but the answer to that question basically told me that it was not the `.get()` method, but the `open` function that was causing it, so I asked this. What makes this different is that here I am asking about the `open` function, not the `.get()` method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing argument error for .get method of tkinter text entry widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461940/missing-argument-error-for-get-method-of-tkinter-text-entry-widget)

Comment: No, I posted that. I found that the problem was not in the get method, but in the open function, so I posted this.

Comment: The code you posted, with `current = open(entry.get(),'w')`, is not not the code you ran, with `current = open(new_name,'w')`.  Get the two in sync, after following the instructions in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You didn't post your entire code, but probably you did something like `from os import *`, which replaced `open` with `os.open`, which does require an integer.  Please confirm, so we can close this as a dup of one of the many similar questions revealed by searching for "open an integer is required".